# Possible for multiple users to login into the same tty

Tags: linux

I'm running an Arch Linux. I installed a display manager. So every time I turn on my machine, it switches to tty1 and there is a login manager GUI. I wonder if it's possible to do the following: while I logged in using `username0` on tty1, now I somehow return to the display manager, without killing my session, and another user reuses tty1 and logs in using `username1`. Much like a user switch, but without having to really logoff first. So I can switch back and forth with everything still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try screen. 
If you start it using

```
screen -S screen-test
```

And allow multiuser access using

```
CTRL-A
:multiuser on
```

And allow another user to join your screen using

```
CTRL-A
:acladd anotheruser
```

You can reattach to it as a different user using command

```
screen -x myuser/screen-test
```

Comment: Can I start an X application, say a window manager, in `screen` or `tmux`, and logout?

Comment: If you just start that window manager inside of *screen* and switch to tty0 then, detach the screen (CTRL-A D) you can easily logout afterwards.

Comment: thanks. not ideally what i'm thinking of. But I guess it behaves the same way

Answer (score 1):

Try `tmux` or `screen` I like tmux much better

Comment: AFAIK, `tmux` moves your processes under a global `tmux` process parent. So they won't get `HUP`ed. But when you logout to switch user, your other X apps will still get killed, right?

Comment: I think that when you log out of a `tmux` session all of the application which are ran under this session stay as they are, that's the whole idea. However, you can explore the options and find what suits you the most. Form your question it sounded like you are looking for a solution in this direction.